# How to get Seq(Table1Type, Seq[Table2Type]) from 2 tables

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I want to get value from parent table and all corresponding rows in second table. Is it possible in Slick

For example, this code,

```
db.run(val crossJoin = for {
  (c, s) <- coffees join suppliers
} yield (c, s))
```

return `Future[Seq[(Coffee, Supplier)]]`, but how I cat get `Future[Seq[(Supplier, Seq[Coffee])]]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305625/translate-nested-join-and-groupby-query-to-slick-3-0 is same problem. Answer compiled, but get run time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Future[Seq[(Supplier, Seq[Coffee])]] you would need to group by supplier:

```
crossJoin.groupBy(_._2)
```

But you need to follow a *groupBy* with a *map* that tells how to aggregate what wasn't used in the groupBy; you need to tell how to aggregate the coffees into a *Seq*:

```
crossJoin.groupBy(_._2).map { case (supplier, coffees) => (supplier, aggregate(coffees) }
```

There's no *aggregate* method to achieve this in Slick, and some RDBMSs don't have it either.

Maybe you have to stick to the usual scala collections api, after you get the Future:

```
db.run(suppliers.join(coffees).result).map(_
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .view.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .toSeq
)
```

Comment: But, this approach remove the original order of result :(((

Comment: I used .view because in scala 2.13 mapValues is deprecated for Map and you need to convert to a MapView first. If using scala 2.12 the .view is not required.